# Detailed "what kind of questions" list

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

Check this out: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/894/what-kind-of-questions-can-i-ask-here-the-detailed-version

Do you think a similar kind of post would be useful here at Android Enthusiasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post seems redundant to me.  All the questions it links to are tagged [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) so it seems that the [tag page](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) would already be useful for collecting them together.

The other problem I see is with people reading it.  It will get buried with time like all Meta posts, and the FAQ is more likely to be seen.

It certainly couldn't hurt, of course, I'm just not sure it's worth the (admittedly minor) bother.

Comment: True, why would we need this vs the FAQ?  FAQ is highly more visible.